# Issue with Responsive Table

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Before letting you know the issue, I would like to present 2 different tables. Here I have a plunker for `responsive table`: http://plnkr.co/edit/WjSQj883tdX92jJoDLaR?p=preview and here is a `non-responsive table`: http://jsfiddle.net/4r6g4cfu/90/ but with various options as export, filter and pagination. Can anyone provide code for a responsive table with options of export, filter and pagination.Which mean I need a table in plunker with options in fiddle example. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you.

I have been asked a few times recently to use tables in projects so I just wrote some code that allows you to have multiple responsive tables on a page. It uses the following logic to set the Table Headers as Table Rows except I don't set the content with hardcoded CSS:

```
        td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
        td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
        td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
        td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
        td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
        td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
```

I had to use multiple work arounds in JQuery as you can't set Psuedo elements with JQuery.

Here is the [preview](https://garathd.github.io/responsive-tables/)

Here is the [code](https://github.com/Garathd/responsive-tables/)

Answer (score 0):

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4r6g4cfu/180/)

Done your table with exporting option

```
<div id="toolbar">
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="">Export Basic</option>
                <option value="all">Export All</option>
                <option value="selected">Export Selected</option>
            </select>
        </div>
<table 
id="table"
data-toggle="table"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-side-pagination="server"
       data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]"
       data-search="true"
       data-height="300"
data-response-handler="responseHandler"
data-show-export="true"
               data-click-to-select="true"
               data-toolbar="#toolbar">

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Job Title</th>
            <th>Favorite Color</th>
            <th>Wars or Trek?</th>
            <th>Porn Name</th>
            <th>Date of Birth</th>
            <th>Dream Vacation City</th>
            <th>GPA</th>
            <th>Arbitrary Data</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>James</td>
            <td>Matman</td>
            <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
            <td>Lettuce Green</td>
            <td>Trek</td>
            <td>Digby Green</td>
            <td>January 13, 1979</td>
            <td>Gotham City</td>
            <td>3.1</td>
            <td>RBX-12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>The</td>
          <td>Tick</td>
          <td>Crimefighter Sorta</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
          <td>Wars</td>
          <td>John Smith</td>
          <td>July 19, 1968</td>
          <td>Athens</td>
          <td>N/A</td>
          <td>Edlund, Ben (July 1996).</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jokey</td>
          <td>Smurf</td>
          <td>Giving Exploding Presents</td>
          <td>Smurflow</td>
          <td>Smurf</td>
          <td>Smurflane Smurfmutt</td>
          <td>Smurfuary Smurfteenth, 1945</td>
          <td>New Smurf City</td>
          <td>4.Smurf</td>
          <td>One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cindy</td>
          <td>Beyler</td>
          <td>Sales Representative</td>
          <td>Red</td>
          <td>Wars</td>
          <td>Lori Quivey</td>
          <td>July 5, 1956</td>
          <td>Paris</td>
          <td>3.4</td>
          <td>3451</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Captain</td>
          <td>Cool</td>
          <td>Tree Crusher</td>
          <td>Blue</td>
          <td>Wars</td>
          <td>Steve 42nd</td>
          <td>December 13, 1982</td>
          <td>Las Vegas</td>
          <td>1.9</td>
          <td>Under the couch</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But the above table is not a responsive one. I need a responsive table like the table in plunker I have posted in my question.